# What is the best way to add DataTable features to PrimeFaces PickList?

Tags: primefaces, picklist

The PickList fits to my use case, but I need some additional features like multiple columns, column sorting and filtering.
Is it possible to use "source" and "destination" DataTables within PickList?
Are there alternative ways to get the features into PickList?

Comment: _" Is it possible to use "source" and "destination" DataTables within PickList?"_ Did you try?

Comment: No, I don't think it is possible. What is your opinion about it?

Comment: Just use 2 dataTables and add some buttons, mimicking the picklist functionality.